# Error using pdfpages and lualatex

Tags: luatex, pdfpages, atbegshi, texlive-2016

After upgrading to Tex Live 2016/Debian i get errors when using the package `pdfpages` and compiling with Lualatex. If i try to compile

```
\documentclass[a4paper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\includepdf{document.pdf}
```

i get the errors

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\AtBegShi@horigin ->\pdfhorigin
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
\relax 

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
\relax

! Undefined control sequence.
\AtBegShi@vorigin ->\pdfvorigin
```

(these are not the complete error messages, just the parts i think are important)

I get no errors compiling with pdflatex.

The versions i'm using are

```
Package: pdfpages 2016/04/19 v0.5f
pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17
LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0
```

Is this some sort of bug, or has something changed in the way `pdfpages` should be used?

Comment: Luatex has changed a lot!!! Among other things dropping a lot of primitives. Have you updated all the packages? Otherwise try adding the `luatex85` package, it "brings back" a lot of the missing primatives.

Comment: BTW: I've added the `luatex` keyword as it is very important in this case

Comment: I've made the upgrade using the Debian package manager, not updating each package individually, so i think everything is updated. Adding the `luatex85` package solved the problem...

Comment: This is a problem in atbegshi. It will be fixed in the next update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LuaTeX has changed quite a lot this year. Among other things the LuaTeX developers removed a lot of known (pdf)primitives from pdfTeX. Thus several packages that make use of these primitives need to be updated.

Alternatively you can add the `luatex85` package, which will reintroduce thise "missing" primitives.

Comment: what is the best way to load `luatex85`, before document class or after?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou no idea, I hardly ever use the package (no need as I don't use luatex), see the manual for it.

Comment: The manual recommends loading it before document class. Thanks.